# Obtaining data from class name

Tags: python, selenium

Currently trying to get the data which is stored in this class using selenium and print it into console.

`<h3 class="tiktok-dvof16-AuthorTitle e10yw27c0">allawi_9</h3>`

I tried  `print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tiktok-1i51bth-AuthorAnchor e10yw27c1"))`

However, it just returns an empty list. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be great!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tiktok-1i51bth-AuthorAnchor").text)
```

Comment: `list object has no attribute text`
Also, this just returns an empty list when not using `.text` at the end.